# Citing RFCs with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I want to cite RFCs in the format [RFCxxxx] instead of using the author's initials and the year it was published. Currently I am using the `alphabetic` style that comes with `biblatex`. So far, I tried using the `\DeclareCiteCommand` command to use the `key` field in the `.bib` file, but that does not seem to work. I would really appreciate any ideas as how to solve this problem.

Comment: This might help some people stumbling on this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65637/how-to-cite-a-standard-iso-etc-in-biblatex

Comment: Also, I found the `manual` class to work well for RFCs.

Comment: Dr.-Ing. Roland Bless generates a `rfc.bib` ["BibTeX file of RFC index (converted daily from RFC Editor's XML index)"](http://tm.uka.de/~bless/bibrfcindex.html), which looks suitable.

Comment: @JoelPurra the link is not 403'd.

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão: not sure what you mean by "not 403'd" -- the link works for me, and the latest `rfc.bib` was generated Saturday, 10-Oct-2015 12:18:42 CEST as far as I can see.

Comment: Sorry for the ridiculous English. Yesterday the link was returning a 403 error, but appears to be working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 27):

The IETF provides official BibTeX entries at

```
    https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/<RFC>/bibtex/
```

For example, the entry for RFC 9405 under https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc9405/bibtex/ yields

```
@misc{rfc9405,
    series =    {Request for Comments},
    number =    9405,
    howpublished =  {RFC 9405},
    publisher = {RFC Editor},
    doi =       {10.17487/RFC9405},
    url =       {https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc9405},
        author =    {},
    title =     {{AI Sarcasm Detection: Insult Your AI without Offending It}},
    pagetotal = 5,
    year =      2023,
    month =     apr,
    day =       1,
    abstract =  {This RFC proposes a framework for detecting sarcasm in AI systems and provides guidelines for using sarcasm without causing offense. By training AI systems to identify linguistic patterns that indicate sarcasm, we can improve their understanding of human communication. The guidelines offer a lighthearted approach to using sarcasm in a way that is both effective and respectful, without crossing the line into offensive language.}, }
```

In comparison, the "Internet Draft" (I-D) [draft-carpenter-rfc-citation-recs-01 § 5.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-carpenter-rfc-citation-recs-01#section-5.2) recommends to use @techreport

```
   @techreport{rfc1654,
   AUTHOR = "Yakov Rekhter and Tony Li",
   TITLE = "{A Border Gateway Protocol 4 (BGP-4)}",
   HOWPUBLISHED = {Internet Requests for Comments},
   TYPE="{RFC}",
   NUMBER=1654,
   PAGES = {1-56},
   YEAR = {1995},
   MONTH = {July},
   ISSN = {2070-1721},
   PUBLISHER = "{RFC Editor}",
   INSTITUTION = "{RFC Editor}",
   URL={https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1654.txt}
   }
```

Note that, while I-Ds are published by the IETF, they are not official (*everyone* can create an I-D).

You can probably add `shorthand = {RFC1654}` as explain by lockstep

Another solution could be to use the [natbib package](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf)

```
\defcitealias{jon90}{Paper~I}

\citetalias{jon90}  Paper I
\citepalias{jon90}  (Paper I)
```

I tested this last solution with the following code:

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\defcitealias{rfc6749}{RFC6749}
\citepalias{rfc6749}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

But I got the result:

```
[RFC6749]
```

and it doesn't changed it in the list.

Comment: You can auto-generate the @techreport entry using [this tool](http://notesofaprogrammer.blogspot.com/2014/11/bibtex-entries-for-ietf-rfcs-and.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `shorthand` field to override the label which is automatically generated by the `alphabetic` style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@report{Cro69,
  shorthand = {RFC0001},
  author = {Crocker, S.},
  year = {1969},
  month = {4},
  title = {Host Software},
  note = {RFC 1},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,Cro69}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This website generates the BibTex entries for you: http://notesofaprogrammer.blogspot.com/2014/11/bibtex-entries-for-ietf-rfcs-and.html

The format is as suggested by this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161413/52398

Comment: many thanks @CGFox