# How to cite a standard (ISO, etc.) in BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex

I want to cite an ISO standard using BibLaTeX. All guidelines I found for BibTeX suggested using `misc` and replacing the `author` and `editor` fields by a `number` field which was then the full string denoting the ISO standard ("ISO 9241-210:2010" say). BibLaTeX won't display the `number` though. I found this [German thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/t-u2Yh9IfaM) where it was suggested to copy the `misc` BibliographyDriver to a new `standard` type (as suggested by the section "2.1.3 Unsupported Types" of the [BibLaTeX documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)) and replace

```
\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}
```

by

```
\usebibmacro{series+number}
```

The result is a complete adapted copy of the `standard.bbx` file, renamed to `din.bbx` though. Is this the only/best solution? Can't I just change what I need and insert it somehow?

---

This link is not TeX-related but might be useful: http://www.garshol.priv.no/blog/47.html

Comment: It depends on the output you're trying to achieve, but often you can get by with style edits in the preamble. I'd put (either manually or with `biber`) the ISO number in a field that forms the citation label. Examples with `authoryear` can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52369/4483).

Comment: Well @Audrey, I'm using `numeric` as the citation style and currently I'm only using normal `\cite`s, not something where the author had to be displayed. So I guess I could get along with `note` or something. But I was wondering whether there was a "proper" way to do it. And somehow, creating a new 800 line file and excluding myself from updates to the original didn't seem proper either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a solution using biblatex 2.0/biber 1.0. You can define your own entrytype for this and then just write your own driver for the new type. Since you "own" this driver, you can do what you want with it, add new fields, format them how you like. This is very easy, I just copied an existing driver from the `standard.bbx` in biblatex and changed it a bit, making it a "standard" driver and referencing the fields I allowed for this type in the datamodel declaration (NUMBER and TYPE). You are really adding to the data model as this already specified that most common fields like AUTHOR, YEAR etc. are allowed in all entry types. NUMBER and TYPE aren't so I added them. I didn't have to actually define these fields in the data model as they already exist - you could of course make completely new fields with new names but then you'd need some `\DeclareDatamodelFields` declarations. See section 4.5.3 of the biblatex 2.x documentation.

```
\begin{filecontents}{test1.bib}
@STANDARD{test1,
  author = {Alan Author},
  title = {I Claim This Technology},
  type = {ISO},
  number = {ISO 9241-210:2010},
  year = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test1.bib}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{standard}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[standard]{type,number}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{standard}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \printfield[parens]{type}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\begin{document}
\cite{test1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have been avoiding `biber` so far because of the lousy toolchain integration. Getting kile to use biber without having my poor Atom do thrice the work it would have to with the usual smart build process seems practically impossible for now. Your solution is great though; it's just too bad that without biber my question seems unanswerable :/

Comment: This is strange - as far as toolchain integration goes, it is a drop-in replacement for bibtex.

Comment: I managed something that looks surprisingly decent so far by making biber a BibTeX "profile" for kile and avoiding `\addbibresource` (which has nothing to do with biber, I know).

Comment: How can I get a pretty shorthand/bibindex for `biblatex` with a style like `alphabetic`? So in the text I get [ISO9241] instead of [Aut10]?

Comment: Just add this field to the entry: `SHORTHAND = {ISO9241}`

Answer (score 15):

According to the [ietf recommandations](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-carpenter-rfc-citation-recs-01#section-5.2), it's recommended to use @techreport for the RFC reference and give some other tips. It may be applicable to ISO too.

```
   @techreport{rfc1654,
   AUTHOR = "Yakov Rekhter and Tony Li",
   TITLE = "{A Border Gateway Protocol 4 (BGP-4)}",
   HOWPUBLISHED = {Internet Requests for Comments},
   TYPE="{RFC}",
   NUMBER=1654,
   PAGES = {1-56},
   YEAR = {1995},
   MONTH = {July},
   ISSN = {2070-1721},
   PUBLISHER = "{RFC Editor}",
   INSTITUTION = "{RFC Editor}",
   URL={http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1654.txt}
   }
```

and I used natbib package to get [RFC1654], [check this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161413/46538)

Answer (score 1):

You could try https://www.ctan.org/search?phrase=din1505, which implements correct citation of various document types according to the German DIN 1505 standard. Caveat: The entire documentation is in German.