# biblatex - How can I change the behavior when using \citetitle for a specific source type?

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to change the behavior of `\citetitle` for a specific source type, which is `standardisodin` (which I got from [*here*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65637/how-to-cite-a-standard-iso-etc-in-biblatex)).

I already managed to get the right order in the bibliography to my liking but I can't figure out how to tune it for citing the title in the document.

Question on the side: should `Type` and `Number` be in italics as well? I like the version I intend to use, unless there is something fundamentally wrong with it I suppose.

### Edit

I'd be happy to manually print out the other fields as well, so I would to write something along the lines of

```
\print{Type}{abc}~\print{Number}{abc}:~\citetitle{abc}
```

or so.

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
12pt,
]{scrartcl}

%%%Tipps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles/13076#13076

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[
language=auto,
style=authoryear-ibid,
backend=biber,
hyperref=true,
dashed=false,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
sorting=nyt,
firstinits=true,
uniquename=init,
uniquelist=false,
autocite=footnote,
ibidtracker=true,
date=comp,
mincrossrefs=1,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%definition of new source type: Standard (ISO, DIN, or other guidelines)
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{standardisodin}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[standardisodin]{type,number}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{standardisodin}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \printfield{type}\addspace%
    \printfield{number}\addcolon\addspace%
    \usebibmacro{title}\addspace%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{related}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Standardisodin{abc,
    Title                    = {Metallische Werkstoffe -- Zugversuch -- Teil 2: Pr{"u}fverfahren bei erhöhter Temperatur},
    Author                   = {{DIN Deutsches Institut für Normung e.~V.}},
    Date                     = {2011-05},
    Location                 = {Berlin},
    Number                   = {6892-2},
    Type                     = {DIN EN ISO},
    Year                     = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
So this is a sentence: as \verb+\citetitle{abc}+ shows, there is no \verb+Number+ nor \verb+Type+ printed:
\begin{flushleft}
\citetitle{abc}
\end{flushleft}
So now, when using \verb+\citetitle+ for this source type, I'd like to have the following output\ldots
\begin{verbatim}
[Type][space][Number][colon][space][Title]
\end{verbatim}
\ldots so it'll produce
\begin{flushleft}
    DIN EN ISO 6892-2: \textit{Metallische Werkstoffe -- Zugversuch -- Teil 2: Prüfverfahren bei erhöhter Temperatur}
\end{flushleft}
in the text.

Question on the side: or should the type and number be in italics as well? I like the version I intend to use, unless there is something fundamentally wrong with it I suppose.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just add a bit of "logic" to the definition of `\citetitle`: We check, if the entry is a standard and if so, print the additional information

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   % this is new
   \ifentrytype{standardisodin} 
     {\printfield{type}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \printfield{number}%
      \setunit{\addcolon\space}}
     {}
   % here ends the new stuff
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

As an added bonus, this re-definition

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {% this is new
        \ifentrytype{standardisodin}
          {\printfield{type}%
           \setunit{\addspace}%
           \printfield{number}}
        % ... until here (save for two new curly braces below)
          {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
             \setunit{\addspace}}
            {\printnames{labelname}%
             \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

will make `\cite{abc}` print "DIN EN ISO 6892-2".

While the definition for `\citetitle` will work with (almost) all (standard) styles, the re-definition for `\cite` is specific to `authoryear-ibid`, but the idea can be abstracted and applied to other `cite` macros as well.

MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
12pt,
]{scrartcl}

%%%Tipps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles/13076#13076
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
language=auto,
style=authoryear-ibid,
backend=biber,
hyperref=true,
dashed=false,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
sorting=nyt,
firstinits=true,
uniquename=init,
uniquelist=false,
autocite=footnote,
ibidtracker=true,
date=comp,
mincrossrefs=1,
]{biblatex}


%definition of new source type: Standard (ISO, DIN, or other guidelines)
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{standardisodin}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[standardisodin]{type,number}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{standardisodin}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \printfield{type}\addspace%
    \printfield{number}\addcolon\addspace%
    \usebibmacro{title}\addspace%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{related}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Standardisodin{abc,
    Title     = {Metallische Werkstoffe -- Zugversuch -- Teil 2: Prüfverfahren bei erhöhter Temperatur},
    Author    = {{DIN Deutsches Institut für Normung e.~V.}},
    Date      = {2011-05},
    Location  = {Berlin},
    Number    = {6892-2},
    Type      = {DIN EN ISO},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \ifentrytype{standardisodin} 
     {\printfield{type}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \printfield{number}%
      \setunit{\addcolon\space}}
     {}
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifentrytype{standardisodin}
          {\printfield{type}%
           \setunit{\addspace}%
           \printfield{number}}
          {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
             \setunit{\addspace}}
            {\printnames{labelname}%
             \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\cite{abc}

So this is a sentence: as \verb+\citetitle{abc}+ shows, there is no \verb+Number+ nor \verb+Type+ printed:
\begin{flushleft}
\citetitle{abc}
\end{flushleft}
So now, when using \verb+\citetitle+ for this source type, I'd like to have the following output\ldots
\begin{verbatim}
[Type][space][Number][colon][space][Title]
\end{verbatim}
\ldots so it'll produce
\begin{flushleft}
    DIN EN ISO 6892-2: \textit{Metallische Werkstoffe -- Zugversuch -- Teil 2: Prüfverfahren bei erhöhter Temperatur}
\end{flushleft}
in the text.

Question on the side: or should the type and number be in italics as well? I like the version I intend to use, unless there is something fundamentally wrong with it I suppose.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding your small question on the side: I think it would look odd, if you set the "DIN EN ISO 6892-2" part in italics as well, as to whether citing standards in this way is sensible: it looks OK to me `:-)`.
I would prefer to be able to use `\cite` to cite the entries instead of using `\citetitle`.
It would be odd to cite those entries with the standard `authoryear-ibid` `\cite` though, as "Deutsches Institut für Normung e. V. 2011" really is not that helpful for a label and "DIN EN ISO 6892-2" seems to be the more common form to refer to them (that's what the second definition above is for).

Comment: Your added note on using `\cite` made me curious. Originally I just intended to put the title together in a proper way. But then, you are right: citing standards in the traditional `authoryear` way would be weird. However I am using footnotes for citations  (-> `\footcite`). Would I have to change anything for that? (I haven't checked out the definition of `\footcite` yet.)

Comment: On first glance, it seems to work for `\footcite` just the same.

Comment: @henry And so it should; `\cite`, `\footcite` and `\parencite` all use the `cite` bibmacro internally (in `authoryear-ibid` at least). It's another story with `\textcite` though ...

Comment: Had another though: would you also omit the issuing institution in the bibliography then, as in actually working "against" the characteristics of the `authoryear`-style(s)? I've seen that before, it would also be in line with the citation then.

Comment: @henry I might have done that, as I don't think the "DIN e.V." is really necessary in finding the citation (it just does not add any useful information - I find). You might think about a separate bibliography for standards and norms then, so our not adhering to the authoryear style does not disturb the appearance of the normal bibliography (via `type`/`nottype` p. 74 of the [`biblatex` docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).