# biblatex - How can I make \printfield{number} just print the number (figures) without "Nr."?

Tags: biblatex

In a [style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199492/biblatex-how-can-i-change-the-behavior-when-using-citetitle-for-a-specific-so) I use `\printfield{number}`. This produces something like

> ISO Nr. 827443

The relevant part on page 140 in the manual says:

> `\printfield[format]{field}`
>
> If the `<format>` is omitted, `\printfield` tries using the name of the field as a format name.

--> What do I have to write in the brackets to have it produce *ISO 827443* only?

Note: leaving them empty via `[]` does not omit the name of the field.

Comment: Does `\DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{#1}` (or `\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{#1}`) help? If not, a MWE would be nice. ... Thinking about it, you probably want `\DeclareFieldFormat[standardisodin]{number}{#1}`.

Comment: @moewe I... feel stupid. How exactly do I have to use that? I put it instead of `\printfield{number}{#1}` and it threw an error. Putting it all in the brackets as well.

Comment: @moewe Pro-user henry can report that `\DeclareFieldFormat[standardisodin]{number}{#1}` of course was to be used as normal code. It all works as intended now. You could provide your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems that you want to change the appearance of the `number` field just for those entries that are `standardisodin` (as defined in [your other question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199492/35864)), you can use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[standardisodin]{number}{#1}
```

to get rid of any prefix to the `number` field for this particular entry type.

If you want to be more radical and do this for all entry types, go with `\DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{#1}`.