# Select (child)entrytype for DeclareLabelalphaTemplate in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, labels

I want to cite an ISO Standard with BibLaTeX as proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161415/63486).

However, as for the citation style alphabetic, the label of \cite{iso704} is "ISO00" and what I want is "ISO 704:2000". The style is fine for everything else, so I don't want to switch the whole style.

So I did the following:

```
\begin{filecontents}{iso.bib}
@Techreport{ISO704,
  Title                    = {Terminology work - Principles and methods},
  Author                   = {{ISO/TC 37}},
  Date                     = {2000-11},
  Institution              = {ISO International Organization for Standardization},
  Number                   = {704},
  Type                     = {ISO},

  Comment                  = {Revised by ISO 704:2009, Revises ISO 704:1987},
  Keywords                 = {Definitions, General section, Methods, Terminology},
}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{iso.bib}


\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate[]{
    \labelelement{\field[]{type}}
    \labelelement{\literal{~}}
    \labelelement{\field[]{number}}
    \labelelement{\literal{:}}
    \labelelement{
        \field[strwidth=4,strside=right]{year}
    }
}

\begin{document}
Actual Output: \cite{ISO704} %ISO00 - Expected Output: [ISO 704:2000]
\end{document}
```

My problem is, that I have to select the proper entrytype (techreport with subtype ISO) that goes into [], so that this does not affect all the other labels.

However, I wasn't able to find any solution on how to select the appropriate entrytype. In the BibLaTeX-Manual they refer to something like @techreport, but even that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bit wicked, in `biblatex` using `@techreport` is just a fancy way of using the type `@report` together with setting the `type` field to `techreporrt`, which in your case is immediately overwritten by your `type = {ISO}` in the `.bib`.

Internally, a `@techreport` is thus a `@report`.

So all you need is

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate[report]{
    \labelelement{\field{type}}
    \labelelement{\literal{~}}
    \labelelement{\field{number}}
    \labelelement{\literal{:}}
    \labelelement{
        \field[strwidth=4,strside=right]{year}
    }
}
```

Maybe the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) is not a hundred percent clear on that when on p. 12 it says

> [`@techreport` is] [s]imilar to `@report` except that the `type`
>   field is optional and defaults to the localized term ‘technical
>   report’. You may still use the type field to override that.

You can, however, find a mapping in `biblatex.def`

```
\map{
  \step[typesource=techreport, typetarget=report, final]
  \step[fieldset=type,         fieldvalue=techreport]
}
```

that clearly shows that a `@techreport` is converted into a `@report`.

---

Since `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` can only distinguish by entry types, if you want something more elaborate, you need to go down a different path.

You can, for example, set the `shorthand` field automatically with the following code

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{techreport}
      \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{ISO}, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorthand, fieldvalue={ISO\,}]
      \step[fieldsource=number, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorthand, origfieldval, append]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{techreport}
      \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{ISO}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=year, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}]
      \step[fieldsource=date, match=\regexp{([0-9]{4}?)}]
      \step[fieldset=shorthand, fieldvalue={:$1}, append]
    }
  }
}
```

Due to the nature of this code though, `shorthand` fields of `@techreport`s that have `type = {ISO}` will be overwritten with the desired format.

In order to avoid this shortcoming we can use the slightly longer-winding

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{techreport}
      \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{ISO}, final]
      \step[fieldset=safeshorthand, fieldvalue={ISO\,}]
      \step[fieldsource=number, final]
      \step[fieldset=safeshorthand, origfieldval, append]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{techreport}
      \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{ISO}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=year, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}]
      \step[fieldsource=date, match=\regexp{([0-9]{4}?)}]
      \step[fieldset=safeshorthand, fieldvalue={:$1}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=safeshorthand, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorthand, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

Here, we construct the desired label in a `safeshorthand` field and only copy that to the `shorthand` field, if the latter is empty.

Comment: Thank you! "report" works as shown, but is there also an option to select report with fieldtype "ISO"?

Comment: @BumbleBee As far as I can see, one can only adjust the format by entry type, not by the contents of arbitrary fields. I do have another idea how we could get around this though, bear with me for a moment.

Comment: @BumbleBee I came up with an alternative that doesn't use `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`, but `\DeclareSourcemap` on the `shorthand` field instead. I have now also removed one shortcoming of my first attempt with that idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend @moewe's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271849/63486): I subsequently had to add a German DIN norm as well. Therefore I extended the code like this:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{techreport}
      \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{(ISO|DIN)}, final]
      \step[fieldset=safeshorthand, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=safeshorthand, fieldvalue={\,}, append]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{techreport}
      \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{(ISO|DIN)}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=number, final]
      \step[fieldset=safeshorthand, origfieldval, append]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{techreport}
      \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{(ISO|DIN)}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=year, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}]
      \step[fieldsource=date, match=\regexp{([0-9]{4}?)}]
      \step[fieldset=safeshorthand, fieldvalue={:$1}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=safeshorthand, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorthand, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

A more general option would probably be to use the type `Standard` and use `ISO 740` or `DIN 2230` in the number field of the `@report`:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{techreport}
      \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{Standard}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=number, final]
      \step[fieldset=safeshorthand, origfieldval, append]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{techreport}
      \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{Standard}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=year, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}]
      \step[fieldsource=date, match=\regexp{([0-9]{4}?)}]
      \step[fieldset=safeshorthand, fieldvalue={:$1}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=safeshorthand, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorthand, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

This might not be perfect, since probably at some point one should define a new entrytype like `@standard` for handling standards in general. But it works out with citation managers like Jabref without the need to declare new entry types.

Comment: You can make your first piece of code more concise by moving the `\step[fieldsource=number, final] \step[fieldset=shorthand, origfieldval, append]` bit to its own mapping just like the date stuff. But please be aware that this solution will overwrite existing `shorthands` for `@techreport`s with the right `type`, this can be avoided as explained in my answer above just at the end.

Comment: I adjusted the code according to your comments. This works now for both approaches.

Comment: If you want to, you can make your code even more compact by combining the first to `\map` directives in the first piece of code into one: `\map[overwrite]{
      \pertype{techreport}
      \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{(ISO|DIN)}, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorthand, fieldvalue={$1\,}]
    }`

Comment: I reduced this code as you proposed, but it didn't work with the `$1`. Suppose I don't fully understand that right now. Nonetheless, it works as above.

However, for other users the more generic solution with the `Standard`-type might be more appropriate either way.