# BibLaTeX: How to ensure to also print "publisher" field when using @misc type?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib, biber, bibentry

Though I have inserted entries for `publisher`, it won't get printed in the bibliography sequence:

```
@misc{VDI3478-Sheet.2008,
    author = {{VDI 3478 - Part 2}},
    title = {VDI - 3478 Part 2 - Biological waste gas purification. Biological trickle bed-reactors},
    series = {VDI-Guidelines},
    language = {german, english},
    publisher = {Verein Deutscher Ingenieure e.\thinspace V.},
    date = {2008},
    type = {Technical advise},
    keywords = {Standards},
}
```

My corresponding `BibLaTeX`-options:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

---

How can I force BibLaTeX to also print the `publisher` when using `@misc` entry type?

Comment: Can't you replace "publisher" by "howpublished" or "note" or something supported there? I suppose that if there is a publisher another type of entry would be better for your reference...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A look at §2.1.1 *(Entry Types) Regular Types* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=11) reveals that the known fields for `@misc` are

> **Required fields**: `author`/`editor`, `title`, `year`/`date`
>
> **Optional fields**: `subtitle`, `titleaddon`, `language`, `howpublished`,
> `type`, `version`, `note`, `organization`, `location`, `month`, `addendum`,
> `pubstate`, `doi`, `eprint`, `eprintclass`, `eprinttype`, `url`, `urldate`

That means that `@misc` does not support `publisher`, but you can use the functionally equivalent `organization` here.

```
@misc{VDI3478-Sheet.2008,
  author       = {{VDI 3478 -- Part 2}},
  title        = {VDI -- 3478 Part 2 -- Biological waste gas purification. Biological trickle bed-reactors},
  series       = {VDI-Guidelines},
  language     = {german and english},
  organization = {Verein Deutscher Ingenieure e.\thinspace V.},
  date         = {2008},
  type         = {Technical advice},% advice or advise?
}
```

Note that `biblatex` knows a dedicated type for standards and norms (`@standard`), but this type is usually handled as an alias for `@misc`. Still, if you cite several standards it might be worth checking out, see for example [How to cite a standard (ISO, etc.) in BibLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65637/35864).